# When I try to start a custom docker image with a specified location it does not work

Tags: docker

I have been working on a Docker file for the past couple days and when I go to start it, it will work if I don't specify a location but when I specify a location it dose not copy anything it needs to that location. here is my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:jammy

WORKDIR /usr/local/spacebar-server

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install curl -y

RUN cd ~ && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x -o /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh && bash /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh && apt-get install nodejs

COPY ./spacebar /usr/local/spacebar-server

RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y && add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

RUN apt-get install build-essential git python-is-python3 -y 

RUN npm install -g npm

RUN npm i

RUN npm run setup

CMD npm run start
```

Back when I made Docker files I never had a workdir so I tried to remove it but that didn't work since npm install needs a workdir. This is the error I get from docker when I start it

```
2023-04-08 09:23:40 npm ERR! code ENOENT
2023-04-08 09:23:40 npm ERR! syscall open
2023-04-08 09:23:40 npm ERR! path /usr/local/spacebar-server/package.json
2023-04-08 09:23:40 npm ERR! errno -2
2023-04-08 09:23:40 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/spacebar-server/package.json'
2023-04-08 09:23:40 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
2023-04-08 09:23:40 npm ERR! enoent 
2023-04-08 09:23:40 
2023-04-08 09:23:40 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I have tried docker compose but it has the same outcome. any ideas why its doing that?

I have tried to remove the workdir but that didn't work I can't think of anything else I can do

Comment: The error states thath there is no package.json, are you sure about what you are copying with the COPY instruction?

Comment: ya its all in one folder. when I don't specify the location it works just fine. did I miss something when I did my copy command? do I need to specify all the files instead of a folder?

Comment: what do you mean by "when i don't specify the location" ?

Comment: if i dont do -v then the location where i want it on the pc, it works just fine

Comment: there is no mentioning of volumes in the original post. If you are mounting a volume to `/usr/local/spacebar-server` don't expect to find something in it other than what it contains before starting the container and what the container writes in it (at runtime, not in the building phase)

Comment: would the copy command copy the files it needs into the direct I specify?
this is the command im using to run the container:
`docker run -d -v /Users/matthewbakken/Desktop/eeeeee:/usr/local/spacebar-server matthew42904/spacebar-docker `

Comment: copy command is executed at build time. If you mount a non-empty volume to the same directory you will "replace" its content. I'd suggest you mounting the volume somewhere else and look for files inside there.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that the COPY command is not copying the spacebar directory to the correct location when you specify a location. Try adding the following to make sure `spacebar` directory is copied to the correct location inside the container.

```
COPY ./spacebar /usr/local/spacebar-server/spacebar
```

Comment: that's not the problem, otherwise npm would not find package json at build time too. He is having this problem on start because he is mounting a volume at the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Docker in WSL? If so, try updating to WSL app v. 1.2.1 or higher (NOTE: This does NOT mean you are downgrading to WSL1; the app and the arch are different).

See:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9921